# URL rewrite with include does not load stylesheet

Tags: php

All my files are in the public_html folder. I rewrote the url of the pages with .htaccess, so e.g the url of `mywebsite.com/balance.php` looks `mywebsite.com/myaccount/balance`.

I can include a file with: `<?php include 'header_login.php'; ?>,` but it appears without the stylesheet.

Both this .php file and the .css file are in the public_html folder.

If I rewrite the url to `mywebsite.com/balance` it works.

How can I make this work with this "virtual" folder in the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.
Always use **absolute paths** in you HTML and CSS files.
An absolute path always starting from `/` pointing to the web-server root.
So, make your css path like

```
/css/styles.css
```

or whatever.

Comment: Thanks! It was easy-peasy :)

Answer (score 1):

The address of the stylesheet is possibly not correct. You have to use absolute paths.

If your structure is like this:

```
/balance.php
/style.css
```

In your balance.php you use: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

And rewrite it to: `/myaccount/balance`

The browser will look for a style.css file at `/myaccount/balance/style.css` .

Just change it to an **absolute path** and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your base url
`define ("BASE_URL","http://www.mysite.com");`
and add `BASE_URL` with stylesheet like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/style.css">
```